# How to make 4 spinners dependent of each others value

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am new to android and was wondering how you can have 4 spinners on a page, but dependent of each other's value. I am trying to make it so that when you select the value of the first one for example the values of the second spinner might change but then I need the 3rd spinner to depend on the value of the second spinner and the same with the 4th spinner depending on the value of the 3rd spinner (because I have so many possibilities). I have the layout set correctly I just cant get the code in my main class to work right.

I have something similar I found online that describes how to do it with 2 spinners but I need it to have 4.

```js
package com.bar.example.androidspinnerexample;
 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
public class SpinnerEx4Activity extends Activity implements
OnItemSelectedListener{
Spinner s1,s2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_ex4);
        s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
        Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(sp1.contentEquals("Income")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Salary");
            list.add("Sales");
            list.add("Others");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
        if(sp1.contentEquals("Expense")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Conveyance");
            list.add("Breakfast");
            list.add("Purchase");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
        }
         
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         
    }
}
```

If anyone could show me an example of 4 spinners that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack snippets are only for HTML/CSS/JS

Answer (score 1):

First initialize your four spinners:

```
s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
s3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
s4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
```

Then set the listeners:

```
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
s4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

And implement your `onItemSelected` method, something like below:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   int spinnerId = view.getId();
   switch(spinnerId) {
      case R.id.spinner1:
          // do spinner 1 stuff
          // spinner 1 has changed update spinner 2 here
          break;
      case R.id.spinner2:
          // do spinner 2 stuff
          // spinner 2 has changed update spinner 3 here
          break;
      case R.id.spinner3:
          // do spinner 3 stuff
          // spinner 3 has changed update spinner 4 here
          break;
      case R.id.spinner4:
          // do spinner 4 stuff
          break;
   }
}
```